# convert all \u symbols into UTF8

Tags: php, regex

example of my test code:

```
<?
$city = "L\u00e9ry, Quebec";
echo 'city original: '.$city.'<br>';
$city = preg_replace('/u([\da-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $city);
echo 'city modified: '.$city.'<br>';
?>
```

my result is:

```
city original: L\u00e9ry, Quebec
city modified: L\éry, Q
```

I'm having some issues... thx

Comment: Aren't there some mb_* functions in the php multibyte string libraries that handle encoding conversions better than manual regex would?  I'm just suggesting, I don't really know for sure

Comment: Just... put the backslash in your match... `\\\\`, since you're in regex.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$city = preg_replace('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $city);
```

Output:

```
city original: L\u00e9ry, Quebec
city modified: Léry, Quebec
```

Comment: Note that this does not replace the sequence with *UTF-8*, rather it turns it into an HTML entity which will only render correctly in an HTML context. The actual data will still be "L&#x00e9;ry".

Comment: @deceze Op wanted to replace it with: `&#x\1` also this is why down Vote?